# Ubuntu LiveUSB not booting in HP laptop

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, hp

I am using a HP Pavilion laptop pre installed with Windows 8. I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop using a LiveUSB, which I created in the conventional way given on the Ubuntu official site.

The problem is that even after changing the boot order to USB Stick in my BIOS, my system doesn't boot from the LiveUSB. It boots directly from the HDD, due to which I don't see the grub menu and system is automatically booted in Windows 8.

I tried the same USB on a different system (my assembled desktop which doesn't support UEFI), and it works fine there. The problem occurs only on my HP laptop.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I tried installing Ubuntu from Wubi, but then there's a whole different altogether. During boot, it shows an Ubuntu option, but reports a missing file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this might be because of UEFI. I did a quick search and found this, try it.

http://scienceblogs.com/aardvarchaeology/2013/12/16/tech-note-how-to-install-linux-on-a-laptop-with-uefi/

Comment: Would be great if you could give the gist of the answer in your own words.

Comment: Thanks @JohnQL. That tutorial did point me in the right direction. Although HP BIOS doesn't have a Fast Boot option, enabling Legacy and disabling Secure Boot did detect my LiveUSB successfully.